# Получение HTML кода нужной таблицы парсингом

Tags: perl

Есть сайт: `http://www.ipcountry.org/index.php?searched_ip=<какой то IP>` Как мне с него получить только вот эту серую табличку(`<\div id="your_ip"><\/div>`)? Я в парсинге вообще никак, никогда не занимался.

Пишу вот(Perl):

```
$ua=LWP::UserAgent->new;$ua->agent("MSIE 7.0 "); 
$url="http://www.ipcountry.org/index.php?searched_ip=$ip"; 
$req=HTTP::Request->new(GET =>$url); $req->header('Accept'=>'text/html');$res=$ua->request($req);@res=$res->content;
```

Он возвращает: `$res=HTTP::Response=HASH(0x93bffa8)` Как сделать, чтобы в $res был HTML код только той таблицы?

Comment: смущает меня такое присваивание `@res=$res->content;`

Comment: А как вы заглядываете в HTTP::Response? Там наверняка внутри нужные вам поля. Вы проверили, что пришёл код 200? А вообще, проще было бы воспользоваться curl или wget.

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее короткий вариант решения:

```
perl -Mojo -E 'say g("http://www.ipcountry.org/")->dom->at("#your_ip")'
```

Если внешний тэг `<div id="your_ip">` не нужен, а требуется лишь содержимое — добавьте `->content_xml` после последней закрывающей скобки.

Подробнее — [perldoc ojo](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/ojo)

В показанном вами виде сервис возвращает только адрес обратившемуся к нему клиента, а не произвольный. Чтоб получить сведения о произвольном адресе, надо, во-первых, использовать метод POST, а не GET, и, во-вторых, результат такого запроса сидит внутри `<div id="searched_ip">`, при этом на странице есть не меньше двух элементов с `id="searched_ip"` — неизвестно, как себя парсер поведёт.

Comment: Can't locate Mojo/DOM.pm in @INC... 
:(

Comment: У вас [Mojolicious][1] не установлен (это часто встречается :-)

Установите его (конкретный способ зависит от вашей операционной системы) — и тогда заработает.

 [1]: http://mojolicio.us/

Answer (score 2):

Вы же почти все правильно написали. Вот только $res - это объект запроса. И там есть переменные, которые отвечают за этот запрос и за результат. Так вот, весь ваш HTML код от запроса лежит в переменной $res->content. А это строка. Не надо присваивать его массиву. Если напишете $html_code = $res->content и в переменной $html_code будет страница. Дальше парсите ее regexp`ом и будет счастье

Кусок кода из cpan :

```
# Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
  my $res = $ua->request($req);

  # Check the outcome of the response
  if ($res->is_success) {
      print $res->content;
  }
  else {
      print $res->status_line, "\n";
  }
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, только парсить HTML регекспами на айс[.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/276994) Куча же нормальных парсеров есть.

Comment: Конечно, HTML он получил, пускай подключает, не знаю, например вот это - http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm и парсит уже полученный HTML.

Comment: @Jim_Moriarty: угу.

Comment: Эх, ну не догоняю я пока парсинг этот... Не понимаю суть работы в смысле как ему сказать что нужно!
Да и многих модулей у хостера моего нет.
Сделал пока так(каюсь):

$ua=LWP::UserAgent->new;$ua->agent("MSIE 7.0 "); 
$url="http://ip-whois.net/ip_geo.php?ip=$ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'}"; 
$req=HTTP::Request->new(GET =>$url); $req->header('Accept'=>'text/html');$res=$ua->request($req);$res=$res->content;    
$res = substr($res, 0, index($res,"</IFRAME>")+9) = "";
$res = substr($res, 0, index($res,"Ваш браузер"));

В результате в $res имею нужный кусок HTML-кода со страницы.
PS не вижу как выделить код.